# Completely erase all records of a commit from gitlab. Including from activity

Tags: git, gitlab

I accidentally pushed sensitive information to a gitlab repo where there's many people working in.

I tried the command `git rebase -i` and `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to erase the commit records, it did erase the commit from the branch's commit history **but the commit is still visible in the Activity section** from the Project dropdown menu.

I also tried:

```
git filter-branch -f --force --index-filter 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch path/somefile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
rm -rf .git/refs/original/
git reflog expire --expire=now --all
git gc --prune=now
git gc --aggressive --prune=now
git push origin <branch> --force
```

but the commit remains in Activity with my sensitive info in a file.

Is there anyway I can completely erase the commit from all records in gitlab?

Thank you.

Comment: I've tried to run HouseKeeping from the settings, still the commit shows up in Activity despite not being referenced by any branch.

Comment: It is somehow a known problem : https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30093

Comment: Trying to figure out if there is some way to manipulate these `refs/keep-around/*` refs

Comment: This should be fixable with a `git gc` on the remote repository. If you d'ont have direct access to your remote repo, try to ask `gitlab.com` support to do this one time operation for you, or ask them for guidance about how to do this remotely.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm having the same problem. The commit is still visible in the "activity section". I'm not using the self hosted version.

Comment: After researching this same issue it appears that on gitlab even if the commit history is purged (ie: project -> commits is 1) the "repository -> activity feed" will still show the entire commit history. From what I read this is by design and cannot be removed. Hence the only solution is to delete the project and re-create it with the required commit history.